# how to make data-live-search-style work for my select

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

live search does not work in my bootstrap select :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith">
    {% for object in array_data_slt %}
       <option value="{{ attribute(object, key_slt) }}"
         {% if selected_key_slt == attribute(object, key_slt) %}
                selected="selected"
         {%  endif %}
       >
         {{ attribute(object, property_slt) }}
       </option>
    {%  endfor %}
</select>
```

What ever I seach it says : No result

Can you help or tell me why?

I tried the :

```
 $('#slt').selectpicker('refresh');
```

but it still does not work. It can find nothing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is data-live-search-style="startsWith"

It does not work for real.

You can use data-live-search-style="contains" which works